# Reload virtual enviroment In django

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

I'm at my first experience with django and I'm having already a little obstacle: I've menaged to create and use a virtual enviroment successufully yesterday, but today I can't seem to be able to reload it. This is how I'm doing it:

```
cd /c/website

python -m venv virt

spurce virt/scripts/activate

cd /c/website/project

python manage.py runserver
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
(virt)
```

before doing some mistakes, do I need to reinstall django everytime or I'm just messing up the procedure to reload the ve I created?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the operating system you are using ?

Comment: For linux, you have to use `source virt/bin/activate`, for windows you have to use `.\virt\scripts\activate`

Comment: are you running this command python -m venv virt every time ?

Comment: You have to create a virtual environment and install all the dependencies once. And then you should just activate the virtual environment you have created. Running this command `python -m venv virt` would create a new environment every time and overwrites the existing environment.

Answer (score 1):

When I got the same issue in my windows machine..(probably occurred  because I did some C drive repair)

I also can't able to run `python manage.py runserver` , I got the same error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django'

I did the following steps.. to overcome my error:

1. On my main folder **Check If you have already a "requiremnts.txt" file skip this step** else run this command: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ,**if it saves all your packages** **then only do other steps**
2. Delete Venv folder from the main directory.
3. Again install virtual environments and activate Venv.
4. then run this command `pip install -r requirements.txt` this will install all your packages back.
5. Run again `python manage.py runserver` , It will work fine